# Взаимодействие между процессами (отправить сигнал программе)

Tags: c#, pipes

Имеется служба, и имеется приложение, при завершении определённой операции в службе, служба должна послать сигнал приложению. Так же, при изменении настроек в приложении, эти настройки тут же должны передаться службе. Как такое реализовать? что использовать для взаимодействия? пробовал использовать Pipes, но застрял на том что необходимо постоянно слушать "канал".
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А сигналы не подойдут? (правда я не знаю, есть ли они в .net)

Comment: Подобное реализовывал используя сокеты.

Comment: А в чем именно была сложность постояно слушать "канал"